# Is there a way to divide a given set of functions (or basic blocks) in a c code to two processors?

Tags: c, function, parallel-processing, code-analysis

Given any set of functions (or basic blocks) of a c code, I need to divide them into **two** (imagine having two processors) so that it could run parallel and could improve runtime performance?

Any idea on how to achieve it? I already have memory access dependencies in between those given set of functions.

Comment: Have you considered threads, such as those declared the standard `<threads.h>` header?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have looked in to threads. Here the problem is I have specific set of functions (methods) and I need to divide them in to two processors considering their memory dependencies. After all to increase runtime performance

Comment: So create two threads and execute the functions you want on each thread.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a thread and set its [affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity).

Since you do not mention what OS you're on, if you're using Windows you'll need to use the [`SetThreadAffinityMask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadaffinitymask) function. If you're running on a POSIX based system (like Linux/Unix and even macOS to some extent), you can use the [`pthread_setaffinity_np`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setaffinity_np) function, but you must take care with that function since the `_np` means "non-portable" and might not work on your target system.

For both of these, they require a native thread handle, which in Windows is one created with `CreateThread` or `_beginthread`/`_beginthreadex` (i.e. a `HANDLE`), for POSIX systems it's threads created with `pthread_create` (i.e. a `pthread_t`).

If you're using the C11 [`<threads.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) header and created a `thrd_t` with [`thrd_create`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_create), then you can pass that as the thread handle to the set-affinity functions, though you might have to cast it to the specific type (e.g. `(HANDLE)tid` or `(pthread_t)tid`).

If you switch to C++11 and use the [`std::thread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/) type, you will have to pass the value returned from the [`native_handle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/native_handle/) call into the set-affinity functions.

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407786/how-to-set-cpu-affinity-of-a-particular-pthread) has some examples on how to use the `pthread_setaffinity_np`, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919699/proper-usage-of-setthreadaffinitymask) has some info regarding `SetThreadAffinityMask`.

As an aside, without seeing code, setting the affinity might not get you want you want regarding parallel performance, you'll need to run some tests on your code to verify that it actually does increase the performance of your code, versus writing tighter, more CPU-cache friendly code.

I hope that can help.